# Is there a way to check if Google Chrome is installed (and default browser) via web page / JavaScript without installing anything to client?

Tags: javascript, windows, google-chrome, browser

Is there a way to check if Google Chrome is installed (and default browser) via web page / JavaScript without installing anything to client PC?
Edit: Or is there something fancy using Flash?

Comment: `["N", "o"].join("")`

Answer (score 1):

Javascript can check what the current browser is.
Javascript can't check your filesystem without your permission.
I think it should be possible to check what browser are installed using some javascript/windows trickery. (how else can gpu-producers detect hardware online?)

Answer (score 0):

No, that would be crazy. Typically javascript is constrained to knowing things about the current browser only, and a few basic things about the computer like the OS and screen dimensions. It would be a security concern if javascript could look through the programs and files on your cmputer.